# How do I find the mean of the value in google sheets by having 2 columns as constrain?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I find the mean of the value in google sheets by having 2 columns as constrain?
For example, my data:

```
Column1|Map|Score

Player A|Map A|23
Player A|Map A|23
Player A|Map B|22
Player A|Map B|22

Player B|Map A|53
Player B|Map A|50
Player B|Map B|14
Player B|Map B|14

Player C|Map A|25
Player C|Map A|20
Player C|Map B|40
Player C|Map B|45
```

In this case, the output should be like this:

```
                 Map A Average         Map B Average
Player A              23                     22
Player B              103/2                  14
Player C              45/2                   85/2
```

Comment: Not sure why the results don't seem to be a average.  For example, why is player A on map B average 23 when the two numbers for that is both 22.  Also what is 103/2 mean?

Comment: It is also best practice to share what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:C,"select avg(C) where C is not null group by B pivot A"))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
=query(A:C,"select A,avg(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B label A 'Averages:'")
```

[image]